# turtlebot coffebot

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I am new to this, and have done the tutorial for coffebot. When running the coffee_bot.py script it gives me this fault.

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1477587719.617954] wait for the action server to come up
[INFO] [WallTime: 1477587719.825782] Kobuki's battery is now: 102.0%
[INFO] [WallTime: 1477587719.825937] Charging at docking station
[INFO] [WallTime: 1477587719.847846] Anyone need coffee?
[INFO] [WallTime: 1477587719.853516] Notebook's battery is now: 96%
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "coffee_bot.py", line 298, in <module>
    while(coffebot.deliver_coffee() and not rospy.is_shutdown()):
  File "coffee_bot.py", line 102, in deliver_coffee
    data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(self.server_public_dns + "/turtlebot-server/coffee_queue.php?pop"))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 290, in load
    **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
[INFO] [WallTime: 1477587720.393432] Stop
```

Have changed `server_public_dns = http://` to my own I got from EC2 mannagment console.
Need some pointers to troble shoot.

Tnks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246541/turtlebot-coffebot/) by [GT](https://answers.ros.org/users/27012/gt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-10-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Coffebot working**

In the tutorial they made `turtlebot_new` this time I made `turtlebot`
I dont know what went wrong, made a new coffebot server in ec2 and I am up and running.
Coffebot is working grate :)

---

Originally posted by [GT](https://answers.ros.org/users/27012/gt/) with karma: 16 on 2016-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0